# Which Software am I Using? Trying to Get Certificate From Certificate Authority (CA)

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

I'm following these instructions to enable HTTPS on a website:

https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

I have shell access to the web host, so I'm trying to use Certbot to automate certificate issuance and installation.

On the Certbot website,

https://certbot.eff.org/

it asks what kind of software I'm using on what kind of system.

I have a MacOS, MacBook Pro version High Sierra, but I don't know what kind of software I'm using between the list of available options:

`Apache

Nginx

Haproxy

Plesk

None of the above`

I would assume that I'm using Apache but I'm not really sure. Does anyone know or is there a way to find out?

Comment: As you want to enable https this mean you will use some http server.Check on remote host what kind is this software

Comment: Though I've helped develop this site for a friend, I'm not paying for her hosting account. I know that she's using the GoDaddy Economy plan: https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting

Comment: They did not mention what exactly is the software so you can get the certificate in PAM format and later convert to other if required. So use `apache`

Comment: (I think @RomeoNinov meant PEM format)

Comment: @davidgo, right, PEM format :)